How can I look in a column of a spreadsheet for a string and put into another column, if another one is found then paste that into a different column
I have a Spreadsheet with a notes column "M" that I want to search through row by row and if anything is found in my dictionary then paste it into column "I" and clear column "M". if more than one item is found then put the first one in column "I" and keep the additional one is column "M".
The problem is that if it finds for example "FRIBDOM10-Southmead" it will need to find DOM10 and it doesn't.
This is my current code;
from openpyxl import load_workbook

try:
    # Load the workbook
    workbook = load_workbook(new_filepath)

    # Example dictionary with potential misspellings
my_dict = {
    'RECY10': ['RECY10', 'RECY10', 'REC10'],  
    'RECY11': ['RECY11', 'RECY11', 'REC11'],  
    'RECY13': ['RECY13', 'RECY13', 'REC13'],  
    'RECY14': ['RECY14', 'RECY14', 'REC14'],  
    'RECY15': ['RECY15', 'RECY15', 'REC15'],  
    'RECY16': ['RECY16', 'RECY16', 'REC16'],  
    'RECY17': ['RECY17', 'RECY17', 'REC17'],  
    'RECY18': ['RECY18', 'RECY18', 'REC18'],  
    'RECY19': ['RECY19', 'RECY19', 'REC19'],  
    'RECY20': ['RECY20', 'RECY20', 'REC20'],  
    'RECY21': ['RECY21', 'RECY21', 'REC21'],  
    'RECY22': ['RECY22', 'RECY22', 'REC22'],  
    'RECY23': ['RECY23', 'RECY23', 'REC23'],  
    'RECY24': ['RECY24', 'RECY24', 'REC24'],  
    'RECY25': ['RECY25', 'RECY25', 'REC25'],  
    'RECY26': ['RECY26', 'RECY26', 'REC26'],  
    'RECY27': ['RECY27', 'RECY27', 'REC27'],  
    'RECY28': ['RECY28', 'RECY28', 'REC28'],  
    'RECY29': ['RECY29', 'RECY29', 'REC29'],  
    'RECY30': ['RECY30', 'RECY30', 'REC30'],  
    'RECY31': ['RECY31', 'RECY31', 'REC31'],  
    'RECY32': ['RECY32', 'RECY32', 'REC32'],  
    'RECY33': ['RECY33', 'RECY33', 'REC33'],  
    'RECY34': ['RECY34', 'RECY34', 'REC34'],  
    'RECY35': ['RECY35', 'RECY35', 'REC35'],  
    'RECY36': ['RECY36', 'RECY36', 'REC36'],  
    'RECY37': ['RECY37', 'RECY37', 'REC37'],  
    'RECY38': ['RECY38', 'RECY38', 'REC38'],  
    'RECY39': ['RECY39', 'RECY39', 'REC39'],  
    'RECY40': ['RECY40', 'RECY40', 'REC40'],
    'RECY50': ['RECY50', 'RECY50', 'REC50'],  
    'RECY51': ['RECY51', 'RECY51', 'REC51'],    
    'RECY52': ['RECY52', 'RECY52', 'REC52'],  
    'RECY54': ['RECY54', 'RECY54', 'REC54'],  
    'RECY12': ['RECY12', 'RECY12', 'REC12'],
    'RECY01': ["RECY01", "REC01", "REC01", "RECY1"],
    'RECY02': ["RECY02", "RECY2", "REC02", "REC2"],
    'RECY03': ["RECY03", "RECY3", "REC3", "REC03"],
    'RECY04': ["RECY04", "RECY4", "REC04", "REC4"],
    'RECY06': ['RECY06', 'RECY6', 'REC06', 'REC6'],  
    'RECY07': ['RECY07', 'RECY07', 'REC07', 'REC7'],  
    'RECY08': ['RECY08', 'RECY8', 'REC08', 'REC8'],    
    'RECY09': ['RECY09', 'RECY9', 'REC09', 'REC9'],  
    'DOM10': ['DOM10', 'DOM10'],
    'DOM11': ['DOM11', 'DOM11'],
    'DOM12': ['DOM12', 'DOM12'],
    'DOM13': ['DOM13', 'DOM13'],
    'DOM14': ['DOM14', 'DOM14'],
    'DOM15': ['DOM15', 'DOM15'],
    'DOM16': ['DOM16', 'DOM16'],
    'DOM17': ['DOM17', 'DOM17'],
    'DOM18': ['DOM18', 'DOM18'],
    'DOM19': ['DOM19', 'DOM19'],
    'DOM20': ['DOM0920', 'DOM20'],
    'DOM21': ['DOM21', 'DOM21'],
    'DOM01': ['DOM01', 'DOM1'],
    'DOM02': ['DOM02', 'DOM2'],
    'DOM03': ['DOM03', 'DOM3'],
    'DOM04': ['DOM04', 'DOM4'],
    'DOM05': ['DOM05', 'DOM5'],
    'DOM06': ['DOM06', 'DOM6'],
    'DOM07': ['DOM07', 'DOM7'],
    'DOM08': ['DOM08', 'DOM8'],
    'DOM09': ['DOM09', 'DOM9'],
    'MRC01': ['MRC01', 'MRC1'],
    'MRC02': ['MRC02', 'MRC2'],
    'MRC03': ['MRC03', 'MRC3'],
    'MRC04': ['MRC04', 'MRC4'],
    'MRC05': ['MRC05', 'MRC5'],
    'MRC06': ['MRC06', 'MRC6'],
    'MRC07': ['MRC07', 'MRC7'],
    'MRC08': ['MRC08', 'MRC8'],
    'Card Support': ['Card Support', 'CardSupport'],
}

# Load workbook and select sheet
sheet = workbook["Inc Multiple Classifications"]

# Get the maximum row count in column M
max_row = sheet.max_row

# Iterate over each row in column M (excluding the header assuming it's in M1)
for row in range(2, max_row + 1):  # Start from 2 to skip the header row
    cell_value = sheet[f'M{row}'].value

    # Convert cell value to string if it's not None
    if cell_value is not None:
        cell_value_str = str(cell_value)

        # Split cell value into words
        words = cell_value_str.split(', ')

        # Iterate over dictionary keys to find matches
        matched_values = []
        for word in words:
            for key, values in my_dict.items():
                if word in values:
                    matched_values.append(key)
                    break



       # If matches are found
        if matched_values:
            # Write the first matched value to column I
            sheet[f'I{row}'].value = matched_values[0]
            # If there's more than one match, keep the additional matches in column M
            if len(matched_values) > 1:
                sheet[f'M{row}'].value = ', '.join(matched_values[1:])
            else:
                sheet[f'M{row}'].value = ''
        else:
            # If no matches are found, keep the original value in column M
            print(f"Row {row}: '{cell_value_str}' not found in dictionary")

# Save the workbook
workbook.save(new_filepath)

finally:
    # Close the workbook
    if 'workbook' in locals():
        workbook.close()

